# What is the shortkey for duplicating a line in VS Codespace

Tags: codespaces

Recently I have switched from VS Code to VS Codespace.

I really miss the duplicate line functionality.

In VS Code you can do this with `ctrl`+`shift`+`d`.
But I could not find a corresponding shortcut in VS Codespace.

Does anyone know what is the shortcut for duplicate line in VS Codespace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set custom hotkeys in the hamburger menu in the top left corner --> Files --> Preferences --> Keyboard Shortcuts --> here type in "Duplicate Selection" --> double click on the result, and press the shortkey you would like to use to duplicate rows.